# "Publishing" a Connected App in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps

I have been developing a Connected App that uses Salesforce authorized accounts (through OAuth 2.0) and the REST API to sync data to a 3rd party app. I currently have this app in a dev account, but I am pretty much done and I would like to put it live in my main Salesforce account, so the customers of the 3rd party app that have data in salesforce, can sync it using my integration.

How would one go about this? How can I "publish/migrate" my Connected App? Would it be as easy as recreating my dev environment in my live account? Or would the app have to be verified by Salesforce and do a bunch of other things?

I read the following [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/App_Distribution), and this is pretty much the publishing case that I am looking for:

> By developing the app in a sandbox (a copy of your production environment) and then deploying the app to your production environment. This is the typical case for companies that have a single instance of Salesforce.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find an example/quick guide on how to do it. Is it literally just recreating an exact replica of my dev environment in production? Is there a way to export a Connected App (settings/config) so I save up some time?

This is my first time developing for Salesforce, so any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting for one single instance then you can directly create the configuration in the sandbox of the customer and test and then use changeset to deploy to PROD.

If you want to publish this app for multiple instances then create a managed package using packages in SFDC developer environment